# ClassCastException in onBindViewHolder of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to display different items/layouts in a recycler view. So this is how I define those items:

```
public class SearchItem {

    public static final int TYPE_DEFAULT = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_LOADING = 1;

    public int type;

    public SearchItem(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public static class DefaultItem extends SearchItem {

        public String title;

        public DefaultItem(String title) {
            super(TYPE_DEFAULT);
            this.title = title;
        }
    }

    public static class LoadingItem extends SearchItem {

        public String icon, title;

        public LoadingItem(String icon, String title) {
            super(TYPE_LOADING);
            this.icon = icon;
            this.title = title;
        }
    }
}
```

So basically I have two types. In the adapter the appropriate layout will be chosen for each item:

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.BaseViewHolder>{

    public ArrayList<SearchItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return items.get(position).type;
    }


    @Override
    public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        switch (viewType) {
            case SearchItem.TYPE_LOADING:
                ViewGroup vLoading = (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.search_item_loading, parent, false);
                return new LoadingViewHolder(vLoading);
            case SearchItem.TYPE_DEFAULT:default:
                ViewGroup vDefault = (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.search_item_default, parent, false);
                return new DefaultViewHolder(vDefault);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {

        SearchItem item = items.get(position);

        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case SearchItem.TYPE_DEFAULT:
                DefaultViewHolder defaultViewHolder = (DefaultViewHolder) holder;
                defaultViewHolder.mTextViewTitle.setText(((SearchItem.DefaultItem)item).title);
            case SearchItem.TYPE_LOADING:
                LoadingViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (LoadingViewHolder) holder;
                loadingViewHolder.mTextViewIcon.setText(((SearchItem.LoadingItem)item).icon);
                loadingViewHolder.mTextViewTitle.setText(((SearchItem.LoadingItem)item).title);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Base view holder.
     */
    public static class BaseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public BaseViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
        }
    }

    public static class DefaultViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder {

        @Bind(R.id.mTextViewTitle)
        TextView mTextViewTitle;

        public DefaultViewHolder(View mView) {
            super(mView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, mView);
        }
    }

    public static class LoadingViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder {

        @Bind(R.id.mTextViewIcon)
        TextView mTextViewIcon;

        @Bind(R.id.mTextViewTitle)
        TextView mTextViewTitle;

        public LoadingViewHolder(View mView) {
            super(mView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, mView);
        }
    }
}
```

In `onBindViewHolder` at

```
LoadingViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (LoadingViewHolder) holder;
```

android studio already gives me the warning that I might get an exception when casting `holder` to `LoadingViewHolder`. When running the project I get:

```
SearchAdapter$DefaultViewHolder cannot be cast to SearchAdapter$LoadingViewHolder
```

So somehow the DefaultViewHolder is casted to LoadingViewHolder but it should not. Instead the BaseViewHolder should be casted. Do you see whats wrong?

Comment: `holder.getItemViewType()` doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have written is wrong as per your requirement and what you are trying to achieve. As i can see the the implementation you are extending not Generic RecyclerView Holder i.e. It would take on Base view holder as single holder

```
extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
```

rather then

```
extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.BaseViewHolder>
```

Here the whole code how to do that

---

https://gist.github.com/umesh0492/e65d5195d8962b1a3049

Comment: SearchAdapter.BaseViewHolder is a subclass of RecyclerView.ViewHolder so this should not be the problem.

Comment: @artworkadシ that's what i am saying, if you only extends BaseViewHolder then you have only access to that view / holder type. You can't play with other views from another holder type. You must extend what i stated above and there i put a gist you can look into it how to do that.

Comment: can you repost your code after the change or  a gist, because you must be doing some blunders while using the mine gist example .

Comment: @artworkadシ dude you are missing break statement in switch (line 39 in your gist)

Comment: AHHH shame on me :D hours of coding made me blind. Thank you man ;)

Comment: @artworkadシ accept the answer also, if it seems helpful  :) . This things happens a lot with everyone :p

Answer (score 1):

It might be late but for the people who are getting the same error.
Use "break" in each case and you will not get any error.